# How can I use a trained LSTM model to make predictions for a single row of setpoints?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, prediction, many-to-one

my project involves predicting yield based off temporally ordered data.
Some background on the data: the data contains sensor readings (ordered in time), that vary depending on the setpoints and initial sensor readings of a particular day.
Based off these setpoints and sensor readings I want to predict yield. I decided to use a many-to-one LSTM model because the operation is cyclic in nature (the overall process involves numerous cycles over a timescale). The model is trained on input of this shape (#rows, 30, 5). Where 30 is the cycle length and the num of sensor readings/setpoints per cycle and 5 presents the number of setpoints and crucial sensor readings. Also the model is trained on output of shape (#rows, 1) where 1 represents the yield (many to one). I was curious if it were possible to make a prediction of the yield based on an input of (1,5). Where we just include the a single row of desired setpoints and initial sensor readings. Or am a limited to entering an entire cycle of information.

Here is how I am shaping the data for training, where I am breaking the data frame up into x and y components. x containing setpoints and sensor readings, and y contains yield.

def reshapeTrainingData(df):

```
cycle_length = 30  # 1-min data collection frequency ~30mins of plant runtime
for i in range(0, len(df)-cycle_length):
    x.append(df.iloc[i:i+cycle_length, :-1].values) # SENSOR READINGS
    y.append(df.iloc[i+cycle_length, -1]) # YIELD

x = np.array(x) (#rows, cycle_length, 5)
y = np.array(y) (#rows,)
```

Thx